# Why is Blender Weight painting not painting any Weights?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, weight-painting

Why when I'm weight painting the blade on this model it's not painting anything, like the blade is rigged to the armature using automatic weights, still I can't paint any weights on it.

Any idea on why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you've chosen the Gradient tool, maybe switch back to Draw? If it's still not your problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i have also tried the draw tool, but still no luck

Comment: this is the link to file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/kMkWAY6x

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment what you see is the vertex groups created by the *Data Trasfer* modifier, disable it. If you want to add to the selected vertex group choose *Blend > Mix* for your brush. Also maybe put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface* unless you have good reason not to:

[image]

Now you can paint:

[image]

Comment: Alright imma try that out and come back with the results in a moment

Comment: Hey, it's working! you just saved me hours of time researching a simple fix,  thanks mate  the issue has been solved 

Comment: @CoreRageEntertainment Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).